# regex replace matched string by another set of characters

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector with strings in the format `"ABC_EFG_AB_XYZACB_95TH"`

For I need to remove the characters at the end of the string following the last `_` invluding the last `_` as well. I tried the following

```
> gsub('_[^_]*$', '', "ABC_EFG_AB_XYZACB_95TH", fixed=TRUE)
[1] "ABC_EFG_AB_XYZACB_95TH"
>
```

The regex passed to `gsub`, `_[^_]*$` looks okay to me - its saying `characters at the end of the string starting with _ followed by any number of characters except _` - However as you can see above it is not working well. I tried this in `RegexPlanet` http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html ( couldn't find something similar for R) it gives perfect match for `_95TH`. What is the right regex to be used in R in place of what I have used above ? Also are there any online regex testers for R ? Do not see any listed here - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: Remove the `fixed = TRUE`  BTW, you can do do this with `sub` too i.e. `sub('_[^_]*$', '', "ABC_EFG_AB_XYZACB_95TH")#[1] "ABC_EFG_AB_XYZACB"`

Comment: @akrun I was about to write the same:-)

Comment: Yet another alternative `sub('(.*)_.*', '\\1', "ABC_EFG_AB_XYZACB_95TH")`